# Floating Action Button is NOT executing OnClick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, floating-action-button

***There is no error for the FAB clicking it just won't execute onClick.  I can click the button and it responds with lighting up but the Toast or log wont print.***

**[MAIN_ACTIVITY.XML]**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recordings_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:text="@string/no_recordings_found"
    android:textSize="@dimen/bigger_text_size"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recordings_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/transparentWhite" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/recordingFab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_record_white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/recordRed"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    app:maxImageSize="35dp"
    app:fabCustomSize="65dp">
</com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
```

**MainActivity Class**

[image: MainActivity.kt]

Comment: Please share your code by pasting a text, not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `fun onClick(v: View)` definition and it should work:

```
recordFabId.setOnClickListener {
    // do your stuff on button click
}
```